# How to flush stray characters from input

Tags: c

How can I handle stray characters input as shown in below code snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main ()
{
    int i, j=0;
    while (j <3)
    {
        printf("\n Enter the number to be displayed ");
        scanf("%d",&i);
        printf("\n The number to be displayed is %d \n", i);
        j++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
philipa@hq1-up-swe-01{1436}: ./a.out
 Enter the number to be displayed 45/
 The number to be displayed is 45
 Enter the number to be displayed
 The number to be displayed is 45
 Enter the number to be displayed
 The number to be displayed is 45
```

Here '/' is added mistakenly. I want to flush this '/' before it taken as input for next loop. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: Please be nice, and also for short code snippets properly indent your code.

Comment: Its unclear for me what you are asking. I tested your code with 45: https://ideone.com/RM3wvv It does not apply a "/" anywhere

Comment: yeah '/' is not added to output but you won't be able to input any other number too. only 45 is taken when you are expected to input 3 numbers

Comment: fflush() or if that doean't help http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html ...

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates for this question on the site... please do some research before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the one single loop,

```
int c;
while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

It will clear the input buffer. Place this after the scanf.

```
while(1)
{ 
   switch(opt)
   {
    ...
    ...
    ...
   }
   while((c=getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF); // It will clear the buffer before getting the next value.
}
```

Comment: I have added the loop on purpose to highlight the issue. I want to know if there's any way to handle this exception. Say while performing operation on Linked list 
while (1)
{
printf("\n 1.Insert Operation ");
printf("\n 2.Display Operation ");
.
.
.
printf("\n 10.Exit");
printf("\n Enter the operation to be performed on the linklist\n");
scanf("%d", &i);
if (i < 0 || i > 10 || i != 0-9)
{
    printf("\n INVALID INPUT !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n ");
    continue ;
}

Comment: You have to do that in the while loop?

Comment: `c` should be an `int` , not a `char`.

Comment: @Karthikeyan.R.S Can you please explain why '/' is causing problem both  the times in the loop.?

Comment: You are getting the input using the scanf mentioning to get the integer. '/'  is character so it does not read by the scanf . So it remains in the buffer.  every time scanf get the value it will come. So the scanf every time fails. It take the first value given correctly, otherwise garbage value.